# How to pass complex JSON object in mvc action method?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have a situation where I get data from ajax call. I want to call an action method and pass data as arguments. The data passed to action method should be mapped to object properties in parameter list.
Here is my class which is called FullQuestion.

```
public class FullQuestion : Question
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Ajax call method

```
var finalTagResultText = {Title: "title", Content: "content",Tag: { tagName: "tname", tagDescription: "tdesc"},Tag: { tagName: "tname1", tagDescription: "tdesc1"}};
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AskQuestion", "Dashboard")',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(finalTagResultText),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Questions", "Dashboard")";
    }
});
```

Here is my action method.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("AskQuestion")]
public void AskQuestion_Post(FullQuestion question)
{
}
```

I want to get the JSON object passed as a FullQuestion object. I used json2 library to make use of stingify method.
I get the title and content text but no Tag object.
Any idea how can i accomplish that ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection property is named `Tags` (not `Tag`) and since its a collection, you need to pass an array of `Tag` objects, for example

```
var finalTagResultText = { .... , Tags: [{ tagName: "tname", tagDescription: "tdesc"}, { tagName: "tname1", tagDescription: "tdesc1"}]}`
```

Side note: Your ajax success callback is redirecting to another page, in which case, do not use ajax to submit your data. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. You would be better off just doing a standard submit and using a `RedirectToAction()` in your POST method.

Comment: Thanks for your help man. It solved my problem. Relating to the advice, I know that posting data with Ajax call probably is not the best way but I have a situation where my data are dynamically taken with another ajax call. So I can not place them in Html helper classes. Maybe there is a better solution to this case but I don`t know how! Cheers :)

Comment: In that case, may be you do need to use ajax (but without knowing the rest of the code its hard to be sure what is the best approach)

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong JSON format, using correct format as follows:

```
{"Title": "title", "Content": "content","Tag":[{ "tagName": "tname", "tagDescription": "tdesc"},{ "tagName": "tname1", "tagDescription": "tdesc1"}]}
```

In order to verify your JSON string, you can use the below link 
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/